# Content Document Parent ID Salesforce

Tags: soql, query, contentdocument, filters, contentdocumentlink

I am completely lost on how to populate a ParentID for Content Documents. I would like to find the parent record (custom object record) linked to the Content Document. I have easily sorted it in the Attachment Object, but having issues with the Content Documents. Grateful for your help.

Finally, I used dataloader.io to try to pull the content document data, as well as Power BI. I saw codes on queries to conduct, but not sure where users input these queries to pull the data needed. Looking forward to your help. #Salesforce #ParentID #Query #SOQL #PowerBI #ContentDocument #ContentDocumentLink #LinkedEntityID

Answer (score 0):

For content document there is another object called [ContentDocumentlink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) where you will get the object reference for which it is related to .

In ContentDocumentLink we have ContentDocumentid and LinkedEntityid which will give you an overview of which contentdocument to related to object.

As per the [object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) of ContentDocument ParentId in ContentDocument object is `ID of the library that owns the document. Created automatically when inserting a ContentVersion via the API for the first time.`